# My Airflow does not connect to localhost 8080, But it is runing on docker

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, airflow, docker-container

It [image] is asking for authentication, but My authentication keys are set to False

[image: Screen shot of docker runing, while airflow asks for authentication]

Comment: why does it mean by your airflow does not connect to localhost:8080? And are you trying to disable web UI authentication?

Answer (score 0):

The username and password was admin, admin. It is resolved